# PHP: 500 Error to error page

Tags: php, .htaccess

As a prelude, I know what a HTTP 500 is, and I know how to fix them.

On PHP 5.3, i'm running a production environment with show_errors off. When there are any fatal errors, the user gets a plain white 500 page in response. I'm trying to create a 500 error page just in case there any any errors; just so it is more user friendly.

I used to be able to do

```
ErrorDocument 500 500.html
```

It doesn't seem to be working anymore, however - even thought my 404

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.html
```

Works fine.

Curious to see solutions regarding this -
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I believe `ErrorDocument 500` would only work if there's a 500 error *before* apache hands the request off to PHP.  I could be wrong.

Comment: @FrankFarmer Most likely - good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fatal errors don't produce 500 errors in and of themselves, they would return 200 with blank page typically (if no output had been flushed to browser at the point of the error) .  Plus this will not help you anyway, as Apache would be no longer involved when PHP is having the error.

Maybe you could register a shutdown function to send 500 header (to get 500 result)  and display the content you want to display.

Comment: good idea, but it doesn't look like a new header in the shutdown function will work. I'll do some further research. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't think this actually possible without enabling errors again, so i'll just mark this as the accepted answer.