# 500 error custom page won't be displayed

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm a front-end developer and don't have much knowledge of htaccess, back-end, frameworks and server configs.
I've built a prototype website (all done with HTML5, CSS, JS and a simple php contact form). All the pages are .php because I have used php include to manage quickly changes on the website.
But my client wants to have a 404 and 500 custom landing pages.

I have put together the layout (html/css) code for the 2 error pages and done a bit of research to understand how to trigger them. I have created a .htaccess file. Here the code:

```
Options +Indexes
RemoveHandler .html
RemoveType .html
AddType text/html .html
Satisfy any
Order Deny,Allow
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

If in my url I type localhost:8888/anywrong-page-name, I get successfully the 404 landing page. But when I try to trigger the 500, I get the standard 500 page and not my custom one.

Is it possible to display a custom 500 page by using only .htaccess (like I've done for the 404) or it's something that it's trigger by the web_config in the server/back-end?

I'd like to know if it's possible (and how) or not without having back-end.

Comment: How are you creating the 500 error?

Comment: How you are “triggering” the 500 error might be the most important part here. If you do it by putting something invalid into your .htaccess file – then of course everything else in there, including your attempt at setting the ErrorDocument 500, gets ignored as well of course.

Comment: I've added a php line of code at top of the index.php file: <?php throw new Exception('Nooooooooooooooo!'); ?>. It does trigger a 500 page, but not my custom page

Comment: Someone made a good point here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12412722/1663306 .. also this comment: I believe ErrorDocument 500 would only work if there's a 500 error before apache hands the request off to PHP. I could be wrong."

Answer (score 0):

In your htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/crash-recover 
ErrorDocument 500 "Sorry, our script crashed. Oh dear" 
ErrorDocument 500 http://xxx/
```

More info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html).